# Class instance creating with class name in variable Ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to do something like that

```
class Foo
 define perform()
  puts 'hello'
 end
end

classname = 'Foo'

instance = create_instance(classname)
instance.perform();
```

Is something like that possible. If is the how?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`const_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-const_get):

```
instance = Object.const_get(classname).new
instance.perform
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible-

```
class Foo
  def perform
    puts 'hello'
  end
end

f = 'Foo'

klass = Object.const_get f

f.new.perform
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Module#const_get](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-const_get)

```
klass = Object.const_get(classname)
instance = klass.new
```

But you might want to whitelist classname first if it's coming from user input. Otherwise you're potentially opening a security hole.